# Lua C API - How to read another value of a table from a C function that is stored in that table?

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

I am creating a simple table in Lua that has various functions and an ID field. From Lua script’s perspective, the table looks like this:

```lua
ball = entity_query.get_first_entity_by_name(“Ball”);

print(ball.id)
ball.name.set(“new name”)
print(ball.name.get())
```

The way I do it is this (I have abstraction over it but here is how the non abstracted code looks like):

```cpp
int getNameFn(lua_State *state) {
  lua_getglobal(state, “__privateDatabase”);
  auto *pointer = lua_touserdata(state, -1);
  auto &entityDatabase = *static_cast<EntityDatabase *>(pointer);

  // How do I get this from the table?
  uint32_t entity = 10;

  const char *name = entityDatabase.getComponent<NameComponent>(entity).name;
  lua_pushstring(state, name);
  
  return 1;
}

int setNameFn(lua_State *) {
  // First argument passed to this function in Lua
  // is at Stack index `1`
  const char * argument = lua_tostring(state, 1);

  auto *pointer = lua_touserdata(state, -1);
  auto &entityDatabase = *static_cast<EntityDatabase *>(pointer);

  // How do I get this from the table?
  uint32_t entity = 10;

  entityDatabase.setComponent<NameComponent>(entity, {argument});

  // same type of logic but to set the value
  return 0;
}

lua_createtable(state, 0, 2);

// Entity ID is stored in the table
lua_pushinteger(state, entityId);
lua_setfield(state, -2, “id”);

// Copied the ID to the inner table so I can access it
lua_createtable(state, 0, 3);
lua_pushinteger(state, entityId);
lua_setfield(state, -2, “id”);
lua_pushcfunction(state, getNameFn);
lua_setfield(state, -2, “get”);
lua_pushcfunction(state, setNameFn);
lua_setfield(state, -2, “set”);

lua_setfield(state, -2, “name”);
```

When `getNameFn` function gets called, I want to read the `id` field from the table that the function is stored in. Is this possible?

EDIT: Added setter function snippet as well.

Comment: `uint32_t entity = lua_getfield(state, 1, "id");`

Comment: This did not work for me because there is nothing at index `1` in the getter function and in setter `1` is the argument passed to that function (from Lua's side). I need to access the table before I can access its fields.

Comment: You need to invoke `ball.name:get` to get `name` object as the first argument of `getNameFn`

Comment: Thank you for this! I did more research on classes in Lua and now everything makes sense.